# Array Type values Insertion in nodejs and Mongodb

Tags: arrays, node.js, mongoose

I'm trying to insert array type values but it gives blank array in database as well as when I use `req.body` it gives blank array. Please Help.
This is the method which I'm using to insert values in database.

```
dealExpiryDate: req.body.dealExpiryDate,
dealExpiryTime: req.body.dealExpiryTime,
availableCoupon: req.body.availableCoupon,
peopleLimit: req.body.peopleLimit,
"$push": {
    dealType: req.body.dealType,
    subDealTittle: req.body.subDealTittle,
    description: req.body.description
}
```

Comment: It's not clear what you are trying to ask. Add complete function in your questions or give additional details.

Answer (score 0):

you can insert directly a an array , as follow

```
var mongoose = require('mongoose');

mongoose.connect('mongodb://localhost:27017/test', {
  useNewUrlParser: true
});
mongoose.set('debug', true);

var messageSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

  content: { type: String },
  likes: [Number]
});

var Message = mongoose.model('Message', messageSchema);

var array = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 10; ++i) {
  array.push(i);
}

var msg = {
  content: "test message",
  likes: array,
}

Message.create(msg).
  then(message => {
    console.log(message);
    process.exit(0);
  });
```

result:

```
Mongoose: messages.insertOne({ likes: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9], _id: ObjectId("5d302f07a938870eb4e8a465"), content: 'test message', __v: 0 }, { session: null })
{
  likes: [0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9],
  _id: 5d302f07a938870eb4e8a465,
  content: 'test message',
  __v: 0
}
```